# Cancelar la edición de la celda de un DataGridView si el numero ingresado no es valido - C#

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

Hace ya unos días estoy trabajando en un formulario de editar pedidos, en el cual poseo una grilla con los artículos que están asignados al pedido.

Mi problema es el siguiente: Cuando edito el Nro.Art de una grilla, tiene que buscar en la base de datos el articulo, traer la información y actualizar el resto de su información, en caso que el articulo no exista debe cancelarse la edición, dejar el numero anterior y mostrar un mensaje de que el Nro.Art no es valido. (adjunto foto del formulario)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pude validar que si existe el articulo, me actualice la información correctamente, pero no en el caso de que no exista.

adjunto lo que tengo de código:

```
    private void dgrDetalle_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((string)dgrDetalle.Rows[dgrDetalle.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[7].Value == "BASE")
            dgrDetalle.Rows[dgrDetalle.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[7].Value = "EDITADO";

        if (dgrDetalle.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 1)
        {
            RepositorioArticulos repA = new RepositorioArticulos();
            long idart = Convert.ToInt64(dgrDetalle.Rows[dgrDetalle.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value);
            Articulos art = repA.ObtenerArtporId(idart);
            if (art != null)
            {
               // si existe el articulo, me actualiza la información 
                PreciosVenta precioArt = repA.ObtenerUltPrecioVenta(idart);
                dgrDetalle.Rows[dgrDetalle.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value = art.DescLarga;
                dgrDetalle.Rows[dgrDetalle.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value = precioArt.PrecioBase;
            }
        }

        if (dgrDetalle.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 5)
        {
            string auxil = dgrDetalle.Rows[dgrDetalle.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
            auxil = auxil.Replace(".", ",");
            dgrDetalle.Rows[dgrDetalle.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value = auxil;
        }

        if (dgrDetalle.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 6)
        {
            string auxil = dgrDetalle.Rows[dgrDetalle.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
            auxil = auxil.Replace(".", ",");
            dgrDetalle.Rows[dgrDetalle.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[6].Value = auxil;
        }

        totalPedidoPagar = 0;
        decimal cantidad;
        decimal precio;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgrDetalle.Rows)
            if ((string)row.Cells[7].Value != "ELIMINAR")
            {
                precio = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[5].Value);
                cantidad = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[3].Value);
                totalPedidoPagar += precio * cantidad;
            }

        txt_Total.Text = totalPedidoPagar.ToString();
    }

    private void dgrDetalle_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
    {
        // cancelar el cambio de articulo si el id ingresado no existe 
    }

    private void dgrDetalle_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Control.KeyPress -= new KeyPressEventHandler(Columns_KeyPress);
        if (dgrDetalle.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 1 | dgrDetalle.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 3 | dgrDetalle.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 4 |
            dgrDetalle.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 5 | dgrDetalle.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 6)
        {
            if (dgrDetalle.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 5 | dgrDetalle.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 6)
                tipo = 2;
            else
                tipo = 1;

            TextBox tb = e.Control as TextBox;
            if (tb != null)
                tb.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(Columns_KeyPress);
        }
    }

    private void Columns_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (tipo)
        {
            case 1:
                if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
                    e.Handled = true;

                break;

            case 2:
                if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != '.')
                    e.Handled = true;

                break;
        }
    }
```

Buscando en internet encontré lo del método CellEndEdit, pero no pude hacerlo funcionar, en el único caso que hacia algo, me entraba en un bucle infinito diciéndome que no existía el articulo y no se podía salir del bucle.

Desde ya, les agradezco a los que se tomen su tiempo en revisar esta situación y sus sugerencias.

Saludos.

Comment: ¿Por que en ves de validar si existe el número articulo, no estableces la columna como tipo ComboBoxColumn?. De esta forma el usuario, solo tendría la opción de seleccionar uno de los artículos existentes, a partir de una lista desplegable, lo que excluiría toda posibilidad de introducir un articulo inexistente.

Comment: Esa fue mi primer idea, pero no pude hacerlo funcionar asique opte por dejarlo como un textbox pensando que seria mas facil, me voy a fijar si puedo hacerlo con un combobox de nuevo. Acepto sugerencias del mismo también jaajaja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya encontré la solución al problema.

Adjunto lo que hice:

Utilice el método CellValidating para el mismo:

```
    private void dgrDetalle_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
        {
            RepositorioArticulos repA = new RepositorioArticulos();
            long idart = Convert.ToInt64(e.FormattedValue);
            Articulos art = repA.ObtenerArtporId(idart);
            if (art == null)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                dgrDetalle.CancelEdit();
                MessageBox.Show("El numero de Articulo no existe.","ARTICULO INVALIDO", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }
        }
    }
```